# Is there a safe, programmatic way to determine if it's safe to open a Swing window?

Tags: java, swing

I have a java app that the user might invoke from the command line by running java -jar app.jar or from a desktop environment by double-clicking the .jar file.

I would like the app to be able to detect if it can safely launch a Swing GUI or if it has to use a command-line interface. If I just start calling Swing functions without checking for the availability of a window system, Java bails out with an InternalError.

For instance, if I unset DISPLAY and run the application, I get:

```
java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to X11 window server using '' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:62)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:178)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:142)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:82)
    at sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.(XToolkit.java:112)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
    at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:849)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:841)
        [etc]
```

I could just try...catch the InternalError and run the command-line interface in that case, but I'd heard that one shouldn't catch Errors because they might leave the JVM in an inconsistent state. (Please correct me if I'm wrong.)

Is there any way that I can check to see if I can safely open a Swing window without catching an InternalError? (I could just check if the DISPLAY environment variable is not empty, but a non-empty DISPLAY is no guarantee that the X server actually works. Nor would that approach work in non-X11 environments.)

Comment: While you should not catch `Error` in general, in this specific case it would probably be ok to catch the `InternalError` (only on a very limited `catch` block that only calls `getDefaultToolkit()`). But since there's a better solution (`isHeadless()`), it isn't necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I could just try...catch the InternalError and run the command-line interface in that case, but I'd heard that one shouldn't catch Errors because they might leave the JVM in an inconsistent state.  (Please correct me if I'm wrong.)

Your understanding is half right.

It is a bad idea to catch an Error *and attempt to recover / continue running* because the JVM could (already) be in a state from which recovery is not possible.

However, catching a specific error, printing an informative diagnostic to the console and immediately exiting the JVM is a pretty safe thing to do.  (The System.out / err streams are pretty resilient to most things that cause an `Error` being thrown.)

In this particular case, there's probably nothing you could do to recover.  So bailing out is the most sensible option anyway.  (Calling `isHeadless()` before you attempt to start the GUI is a better idea though.)

Comment: Thanks! In my case, because isHeadless() was false even if DISPLAY was unset (or set to something bogus, like localhost:38219), I caught the error this way and told the user to pass a command-line parameter to force the app into CLI mode. I'd rather just run the CLI mode, but if the JVM might be unsafe after catching an InternalError, I'll avoid that.

Comment: That's interesting.  According to this - http://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=361439#c2 - `isHeadless()` should work if DISPLAY is unset ... though it won't if it is set to something bogus.

Answer (score 15):

You can use [`GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.html#isHeadless%28%29)

Comment: Do you think `awt.GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless()` is also suitable for SWT-enabled applications?

Comment: @谢继雷: while SWT-enabled applications will generally require the same resources (X11 on unix-like OS, ...), I don't think it's appropriate to call this for SWT, as it would add a dependency on AWT to your SWT-enabled app that would otherwise not exist. I wouldn't be surprised if SWT had a similar call on its own.

Comment: Thanks! But that doesn't seem to work for me. At least in my environment, GraphicsEnvironment.isHeadless() returns false if I unset DISPLAY and run the program.