# JavaFX 8 + Spring Boot, Print API not showing the Page Setup

Tags: java, spring-boot, javafx, printing

I have a simple Spring Boot + JavaFX 8 application like so:

```
package com;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.print.PrinterJob;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Main extends Application {

    protected ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        springContext = springBootApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) {
        // Create the PrinterJob
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();

        if (job == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Show the page setup dialog
        boolean proceed = job.showPageSetupDialog(stage);

        if (proceed)
        {
            System.out.println("SUCCESS");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        springContext.close();
    }


    private ConfigurableApplicationContext springBootApplicationContext() {
        SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Main.class);
        String[] args = getParameters().getRaw().toArray(new String[0]);
        return builder.run(args);
    }
}
```

The problem is that it prints `SUCCESS` without showing a Page Setup at all regardless of the OS (I'm currently working on Linux). Example from [here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/javafx/javafx-print-api/#page) (section 5. Showing the Print Dialogs), however, works as intended. Why does my Spring Boot app not work while the second example does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that Spring Boot sets the `java.awt.headless` property to `true` by default, which makes the app run in headless mode, hence not showing the print setup. I solved it simply debugging the code and then following those two SO questions:

- [How to determine if GraphicsEnvironment exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610525/how-to-determine-if-graphicsenvironment-exists)
- [Setting java.awt.headless=true programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552371/setting-java-awt-headless-true-programmatically)

so my final code is as follows:

```
package com;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.print.PrinterJob;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Main extends Application {

    protected ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false");
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        springContext = springBootApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) {
        // Create the PrinterJob
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();

        if (job == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Show the page setup dialog
        boolean proceed = job.showPageSetupDialog(stage);

        if (proceed)
        {
            System.out.println("SUCCESS");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        springContext.close();
    }


    private ConfigurableApplicationContext springBootApplicationContext() {
        SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Main.class);
        String[] args = getParameters().getRaw().toArray(new String[0]);
        return builder.run(args);
    }
}
```